# java8 Function reference IllegalAccessError

Tags: java, java-8

```java
Function<StringBuilder,Integer> function = StringBuilder::length;
System.out.println(function.apply(new StringBuilder("abcd")));
```

Console

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder from class stream.CollectCollector
    at stream.CollectCollector.lambda$main$0(CollectCollector.java:25)
```

problem resoled!!!
jdk bug 
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8162779

Comment: Does look like programming error Function function=StringBuilder::length why are you using "::" c++ operator in java?

Comment: @Fairoz That is a Java 8 method reference

Comment: Is this an XY problem? I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: This code works, please make a [mcve].

Comment: I think the issue is specific to some JDK or JRE version since some of you guys can't reproduce the error. I use java version "1.8.0_66" to compile the code and got the error. I think it will be useful if you guys can specify your java version. Trying with java version "1.8.0_92", but still have the error

Comment: I tried with the newest jdk1.8.0_102 and it's succeed without any error. So it confirmed because of the java version

Comment: It must be this bug then https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8162779

Comment: According to [this bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8152643) the problem has been fixed in the JDK8u102.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's trying to access `AbstractStringBuilder`, the class that implements the `length` method but it has local visibility.

You can change it by reflection but the easiest way to fix this is to change your code to:

```
Function<StringBuilder,Integer> function = sb -> sb.length();
System.out.println(function.apply(new StringBuilder("abcd")));
```

Answer (score 1):

StringBuilder extends AbstractStringBuilder.
If you use method reference with StringBuilder::length, to StringBuilder, it will refer to AbstractStringBuilder.length().
And because AbstractStringBuilder has a default access modifier, it can't be accessed outside from the default package(java.lang), so it will throw that error

Comment: Why java8 does not support such an approach it, this problem will lead to a runtime error , it is easy to cause problems

Comment: @printfabcd Actually java8 support that method reference, but this error happens because of the access modifier of the parent class make that class can't be accessed by your current class. StringBuilder itself doesn't override the length method of AbstractStringBuilder. So that's why when you use StringBuilder::length, it will search the method to the parent class

Comment: There is no error... the code in the question works. `length()` is a public method, inherited as public in `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Not the method, but the class access modifier "abstract class AbstractStringBuilder". If you notice, it doesn't have any method modifier(package default). The case will be different if it has a public access modifier: "public abstract class AbstractStringBuilder"

Comment: That isn't taken into account. `length()` is public, that's all it matters. A class not in same package won't be able to subclass `AbstractStringBuilder` because of the package modifier, for sure. But if you interact with a public class inheriting from it, the public methods from the superclass are accessible without issue.